# Why does VS Code colour JavaScript's `Math` and `Number` differently?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Take Math.random and Number.MAX_VALUE function.

Why is Number green and the other Blue (for my colour theme). This also applies to static methods on Number.

[image]

Comment: Because they designed it to for different types of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the token scopes using `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, you'll see:

- For `Math`: "semantic token type: variable"
- For `Number`: "semantic token type: class"

This makes sense I think. In lib.es5.d.ts:

```
interface NumberConstructor {
    new(value?: any): Number;
    ...
}
...
declare var Number: NumberConstructor;
...
interface Math {
    ... // no constructor (`new` function)
}
declare var Math: Math;
```

The `new` function in the `NumberConstructor` type declaration is providing typings for the `Number` constructor, which indicates to TypeScript that `Number` is a class. But not so for the `Math` type.